# Setting locale only on local machine JVM

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, locale

I need to change my Java locale to another language system-wide for work purposes, but there seems to be no easy way to do it by default. I do development for CJK applications, but changing my actual system locale to match also renames my home folders, meaning if my input method decides to stop working I would have to reboot my entire system.

I've tried setting JVM arguments (`-Duser.language=ja -Duser.locale=JP`) on

- maven command line arguments (really not what I want but tried out of desperation)
- `{$project_dir}/.mvn/jvm.config` (not ideal)
- environment `JAVA_ARGS` (under `/etc/environment`)
- maven JVM arguments in eclipse/intellij
- `MAVEN_OPTS`

but none of them work. Pretty much at my wits end here.

To be clear I'm looking for a solution with the following criteria:

- Not project specific
- Doesn't require project source modification (e.g. project properties files) outside of `.mvn`
- Doesn't involve changing my actual system locale (`en_US`)
- Doesn't require constant maintenance (e.g. constantly add command line arguments)

So basically some kind of environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can include these properties on your `application.properties` or `application.yaml`:

```
spring.mvc.locale=pt_BR
spring.mvc.locale-resolver=fixed
```

Changing the locale to the one you need.

These properties are used to defined the locale when the `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` is being configured, through the following method:

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.mvc", name = "locale")
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        if (this.mvcProperties.getLocaleResolver() == WebMvcProperties.LocaleResolver.FIXED) {
            return new FixedLocaleResolver(this.mvcProperties.getLocale());
        }
        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(this.mvcProperties.getLocale());
        return localeResolver;
    }
```

You can check also the source code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L277)

Comment: That would work on a per-project basis, but I'm specifically looking for something that would apply system-wide. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Currently they're `spring.web(flux).locale` and `spring.web(flux).locale-resolver` properties.

Answer (score 2):

Your `-Duser.locale=JP` JVM argument should be `-Duser.country=JP`.

From [Oracle technical resource on Locale](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/locale.html):

> ... on some Java runtime implementations, the application user can override the host's default locale by providing this information on the command line by setting the `user.language`, `user.country`, and `user.variant` system properties.

(not a complete answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment)

Answer (score 1):

You can try settig jvm parameters like (presudocode)

First way, you can do it like this-

`java -Duser.country=CA -Duser.language=fr ........`

Second way would be to call method

`Locale.setDefault(Locale)`

above method will set it jvm wise locale.

Third way, as per docs

> Using an Explicit Locale
>
> In some computing environments, applications use only a single locale
>   throughout their life cycle. In other environments, applications use a
>   global locale that can be changed. Those environments allow you to
>   programmatically change the global locale preference, which remains in
>   effect until you explicitly change it again. The Java application
>   environment is unique, providing you with the ability to use a variety
>   of locales throughout your application in any way you require.
>
> Multinational companies have customers all around the globe. This
>   means that both their customers and employees may speak different
>   languages and have different expectations for how the company and its
>   software should behave. Moreover, it is entirely possible, even
>   common, to have a French employee handle a sales record for an Italian
>   customer. In those situations, you will need absolute control over
>   which locale your business and user interface objects use to
>   manipulate and represent data. Your application may need to print
>   sales receipts using Italian date and currency formats, yet sort
>   customer lists for an English sales employee. The combinations are far
>   too numerous to list, but Java technology provides you the flexibility
>   to handle that complexity.
>
> In order to get the most flexibility, you must explicitly request
>   support for a target locale for each locale-sensitive class that you
>   use. That means you must track the locale preferences for multiple
>   aspects of the application or assign locale preferences to different
>   users and customers.
>
> If you have tracked the user's locale preference, you would create
>   instances of locale-sensitive classes by explicitly providing a locale
>   in a constructor or creation method. Imagine that a preferences object
>   stores your customer's locale choice:

```
Locale userLocale = preferences.getLocale(); 
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(userLocale);
```

So, in here, you can store your customer locale prefernce in this [Preference object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html)  api, then do the required formatting operation etc.

What you can do is, set one global locale or leave one default locale.
And whenever required, set explicitly the required "locale" in the method.

Kindly go throw the following links as well-

https://www.top-password.com/blog/tag/change-system-locale-windows-command-line/

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/locale-140624.html#using

Comment: Would I have to call Locale.setDefault everytime I start a JVM? The docs aren't clear on that point. If so then it's not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: @tacobot Yes, the JVM has a current default locale during runtime. The `Locale.setDefault` changes the default during runtime, but that change is not persisted. Also, be aware that `Locale.setDefault` immediately affects all code in all threads of all apps within that JVM. Therefore I do not recommend it.

Comment: @BasilBourque, he should set the locale explicitly, whenever, he does perform processing.

Comment: I don't want to have to set the locale manually everytime I start a JVM.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM maintains its own current default locale. This behavior is required by the Java specifications.

Typically a JVM implementation detects the host OS default when the JVM starts up, and uses that as its own default. Later changing the host OS’ current default has no effect on the JVM. This behavior is *not* specified in the Java specs.

You can typically override that behavior by specifying a default locale on the command-line used to launch the JVM. You said you tried this, but did not explain why this is not a solution. This behavior is *not* specified in the Java specs.

## Externally monitor & manipulate

You could externally monitor and manipulate the locale within Java by opening some communication path.

[JMX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/) springs to mind.

## External look-up

When your app starts, it could look in an external source for an idea of what locale to use, then make that a singleton within your app.

An [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) server is one such external place to hold such values. You would use [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) in Java to access the server and retrieve the value.

## Call `Locale.setDefault`

Calling `Locale.setDefault` immediately affects all code in all apps within the JVM. But this does not persist. You must call again when relaunching your app or JVM.

Any other code can call this as well as your code, making it unreliable. I do not recommend this approach.

You can hard-code the desired `Locale` by declaring a static class variable.

```
static final public Locale LOCALE = Locale.ITALY ;
```

In the lifecycle code called when your app launches, call `Locale.setDefault( SomeClass.LOCALE ) ;`.

## Pass `Locale` object in your code

➥ I suggest always passing `Locale` explicitly as the optional argument in the various places you care about.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;  // Pass explicitly your desired/expected `Locale`.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = today.format( f ) ;
```

> mardi 11 juin 2019

Depending on the JVM’s current default locale is unreliable. As a programmer you are depending on externalities you cannot control.

- The sysadmin or end-user may alter the default in deployment.
- Any code in any thread of any app or library within the JVM calling `Locale.setDefault` immediately affects your code.

By the way, same goes for time zone, `ZoneId`. Better to always pass explicitly your desired/expected time zone.

Also, if the locale or time zone is crucial, best to confirm with the user.

Comment: command-line arguments aren't ideal for me because I would have to copy paste the arguments across run configurations for every project across all my IDEs, so I was looking for a way to avoid that. I've also tried setting it in IDE VM arguments (Eclipse) but it didn't pan out. I don't want to change my system locale because I run Ubuntu and if ibus decides to call it a day I have to reboot my entire system to keep working since all the home folder names get localised.

Comment: @tacobot Setting the VM arguments in Eclipse is the development-time same thing as the deployment-time option of adding arguments to the command-line invocation of the JVM.

Comment: @tacobot You should post clarifications as edits to the body of your Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: I'm more concerned with the part where I have to constantly maintain it. If I could just get the JVM settings to work inside an Eclipse/IntelliJ-wide setting that would be fine too. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I've found that works for me is setting `LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8` as an actual system environment variable on my IDEs that kicks in after boot (both eclipse and intellij provide this under run configurations). But I really really dislike this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a slightly related answer here because I ended up here when googling;

I've had some issues specifically when running test cases in IntelliJ. Finally figured out that you have to set `-Duser.language=en` in relevant "Run/Debug Configuration Template(s)"